# APCu Adapter & Symfony 3.3 -> Error

Tags: php, symfony, service, controller, adapter

I am trying to plug APCu into the Symfony 3.3 test project.
I am getting an error, when I add `ApcuAdapter` to `AppKernel.php`.
Here is the list of what I have done:

1. in `./app/AppKernel.php` i have added a "new" line to `$bundles` in `public function registerBundles()`:

   ```
   public function registerBundles()
   {
       $bundles = [
           ... ,
           new Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\ApcuAdapter()
       ];

       ...

       return $bundles;
   }
   ```
2. Opened the project's site. It shows an error:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "getName" of class "Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\ApcuAdapter".

(`./` means the root folder of the project)

Please, tell me why does this error happen and how to plug this adapter into the symfony framework. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't this adapter already a piece of the Framework itself? There shouldn't be a need to add it in. Plus, that Adapter is not a bundle in a sense that you add it to `registerBundles()` in `AppKernel.php`

Comment: If it is embedded, then how do I run `apcu_exists` function from symfony 3.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

me have found the solution somewhere on the framework's website.

somehow, we should use not the `Adapter`, but the `Simple` instead. 
seems very un-logical to me.

so, the Service now works and looks this way:

```
    <?php

    namespace AppBundle\Service;

    use Symfony\Component\Cache\Simple\ApcuCache;

    class ApcuTester
    {
        public function __construct
        (
        )
        {

        }

        public function testMe()
        {
            $cache = new ApcuCache();

            $TestVar_dv = 0;
            $TestVar_vn = 'TestVar';
            $TestVar = NULL;

            //$cache-> deleteItem($TestVar_vn); // dbg

            // Read
            if ( $cache->hasItem($TestVar_vn) )
            {
                $TestVar = $cache->get($TestVar_vn);
            }
            else
            {
                $cache->set($TestVar_vn, $TestVar_dv);
                $TestVar = $TestVar_dv;
            }

            // Modify
            $TestVar++;

            // Save
            $cache->set($TestVar_vn, $TestVar);

            // Return
            return $TestVar;
        }
    }
```

And the Controller which executes this Service looks as this:

```
    <?php

    namespace AppBundle\Controller;

    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

    use AppBundle\Service\MessageGenerator;
    use AppBundle\Service\ApcuTester;

    class LuckyController extends Controller
    {
        /**
        * @Route("/lucky/number", name="lucky")
        */
        public function numberAction
        (
            Request $request, 
            MessageGenerator $messageGenerator,
            ApcuTester $apcuTester
        )
        {
            $lucky_number = mt_rand(0, 100);

            $message = $messageGenerator->getHappyMessage();

            $testvar = $apcuTester->testMe();

            $tpl = 'default/lucky_number.html.twig';
            $tpl_vars = 
            [
                'lucky_number' => $lucky_number,
                'message' => $message,
                'testvar' => $testvar
            ];

            return $this->render($tpl, $tpl_vars);
        }
    }
```

If i wrote the same thing in pure PHP i would have done it an hour earlier :) Oh these crazy frameworks...